# jquery inheritance of methods/functions

Tags: jquery, inheritance

So I have a table, and Im adding the ability to add a new table row once the user
clicks on "add new" button. The problem is that initially the table has 4 rows,
when I click "add new" button on any of these 4 rows it adds a new row, but If I click "add new" button on any of the newly created rows no rows are created. These newly created rows are not inheriting this 'add row' functionality.
Im relatively new to jquery and I know just the basics (what I need in
my projects). So here is my code:

```
$('.new-row').on('click', function(){
        var add_parent_div_id = $(this).parent().data('divid');
        var last_row = last_row_id();
                var cl="gray";

        //add a new row
        $('[data-divid="'+add_parent_div_id+'"]').after('<div class="cell '+ (cl) +'" data-divid="'+ (++last_row) +'" ><div class="new-row"></div><div class="item-cell"><input type="text" value="Item name..." ></input></div> <div class="qty-cell"><input type="text" value="1" ></input></div> <div class="price-cell"><input type="text" value="0.00" ></input></div> <div class="discount-cell" ><input type="text" value="0.00" ></input></div> <div class="subtotal-cell"><input type="text" value="0.00" ></input></div><div class="remove-row"></div></div>');

    });
```

So once you click the add button it appends a new row.

How can I make it so that the newly created row will listen to this

```
$('.new-row').on('click', function(){
```

and add a new row....

As a jquery newbie, I'd appreciate any code structuring suggestion as well any best practice recommendation regarding this...

Thank you.

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: @KevinB you mean http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Another great example of the introductory "so".